# Push form submissions to array

Tags: javascript

I have a blog with 2 sections: posts and a form to post. There is an array of objects in which post data is stored (author, date, content, title). I'd like to be able to push new entries to the posts array with the form and display the new array upon refreshing the page. Can I do that? If not, how should this problem be solved? I cannot use a server and all files need to be local.

```js
var posts = [{
        author: "Gabriel Alexandrescu",
        title: "Prajiturile cu ciocolata",
        content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi felis magna, sodales commodo varius a, \
        pulvinar ac enim. Etiam vitae tortor eleifend, mollis magna id, venenatis purus. Nam vestibulum feugiat \
        condimentum. Nulla volutpat lacus et urna vehicula, eu accumsan nibh iaculis. Sed quis efficitur leo, in \
        malesuada sem. Etiam interdum velit justo, eget congue eros molestie sit amet. Nulla et tincidunt nibh.",
        date: "04/02/2018"
    },
    {
        author: "Laura Oprisan",
        title: "Masinile hybrid",
        date: "12/03/2018",
        content: "Nulla facilisi. Morbi urna mi, commodo a lacus at, rhoncus malesuada mi. Vivamus accumsan tempus \
        magna vitae pellentesque. Morbi rutrum risus ligula, ac posuere est finibus eu. Duis semper porta magna, \
        eget pulvinar neque lacinia vitae. Vestibulum luctus sollicitudin nisl, in hendrerit lacus vehicula eu. \
        Curabitur venenatis ipsum ut dignissim consectetur. Ut pellentesque vitae nulla eu finibus. Nulla facilisi. \
        Suspendisse sem nibh, tristique nec venenatis sed, fringilla at libero. Nullam et nisl eget urna sodales \
        semper sit amet eu ex. Quisque ut risus eget metus porta euismod. Nam imperdiet ipsum non tortor maximus, \
        non varius lacus commodo. Nam rutrum tellus metus, et luctus ex facilisis efficitur. Suspendisse ut augue \
        porta ex suscipit varius sed et metus."
    },
    {
        author: "Alin Popescu",
        title: "Cafeaua in ziua de azi",
        date: "10/05/2018",
        content: "Integer mi ante, luctus quis sagittis nec, rhoncus elementum magna. Morbi ultricies consequat urna. \
        Pellentesque at lorem sed neque sodales vehicula. Nam massa lectus, pharetra et feugiat non, pellentesque in \
        elit. Donec consectetur iaculis neque, ac pharetra turpis. Sed molestie mauris et arcu ultrices, vitae vehicula \
        erat rutrum. Quisque justo massa, rhoncus rhoncus imperdiet vitae, blandit vitae magna."
    }
]

function renderPosts() {
    let postsList = document.getElementById("postsList");
    posts.forEach((element, index) => {
        postsList.innerHTML += `<li>
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="noMargin">
                ${element.title}
            </h3>
            <h5 class="noMargin">By
                ${element.author} |
                    ${element.date}
            </h5>
            <p>
                ${element.content}
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>`;
    });
}

function start() {
    renderPosts();
}

function submit() {
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var formattedDate = nowDate.getDate() + '/' + (nowDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + nowDate.getFullYear();

    var newAuthor = document.getElementById("form").elements[0].value;
    var newtitle = document.getElementById("form").elements[1].value;
    var newContent = document.getElementById("form").elements[2].value;

    var newPost = {
        author: newAuthor,
        title: newTitle,
        content: newContent,
        date: formattedDate
    }
    posts.push(newPost);
    location.reload();
}

window.addEventListener("load", start);
```

```html
<h1>Add post</h1>
            <form class="form" id="form">
                <label>Author</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="otherFields">
                <br>
                <label>Title</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="otherFields">
                <br>
                <label>Content</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="content" class="contentField">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" onClick="submit()">
            </form>
```

Comment: That array data is going to be lost on page refresh, unless your persisting it somehow (like cookies or localstorage or sessionstorage).

Comment: store data in localstorage , detecting if user is reloading the page with `onbeforeunload` etc and then get if back from there when page is reloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). You're going to need some type of storage on the page reload unless you're going to attach the values into a get request (which might not be possible because of how long the descriptions are in your sample data).

Local Storage will set the values in the browsers storage, where they can be fetched on reload.

```
posts = {};
if(localStorage.getItem('posts')) {
    posts = json.parse(localStorage.getItem('posts'));
    renderPosts();
}
```

something like that will get you started on pulling from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is a client side only.
Here a simple but functional example https://jsfiddle.net/jeu0kbbq/ without the need of first setting of posts would be:

```
 if(localStorage.getItem("posts")){
            posts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("posts")); 
        }else{
            posts = [];
            localStorage.setItem("posts", JSON.stringify(posts));
        }
```

Of course using localStorage and no server side code and/or database clients will not be able share information at all. Information is stored in clients browsers, each browser will have it's own information.

I think this a good approach to secure manage information for clients only, since there is no network activity at all.